# Reading words of lines and storing words at 3D Array

Tags: c, string, file, multidimensional-array

I am dealing with such a problem that, I have one input file that contains words of lines, and I have wanted to store all words line by line with 3D-Array. But something seems wrong with my code, I think that I cannot see the point of where the segmentation fault is happening. Here is my code: For clarifications:

"**char *input**" is a **filename** | 
"**MAX_WORDS**" is a macro that is equivalent to **500** | 
"**MAX_WLENGTH**" is another macro that is equivalent to **64**.

```
void func(char *input){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(input, "r");
    char buffer[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORDS][MAX_WLENGTH];
    if(fp != NULL){
            int c;
            size_t i = 0;
            size_t x = 0;
            size_t y = 0;
            for(;;){
                    c = fgetc(fp);
                    if(c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != ' '){
                            if(i < MAX_WLENGTH -1){
                                    buffer[y][x][i++] = c;
                            }
                            continue;
                    }
                    if (i > 0){
                            buffer[y][x][i] = '\0';
                            if(c == '\n'){
                                    y++;
                                    x = 0;
                                    i = 0;
                            }
                            else if(c == ' '){
                                    x++;
                                    i = 0;
                            }
                    }
                    if(c == EOF){
                            break;
                    }
            }
            fclose(fp);
    }

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_WORDS; ++i){
         printf("\n");
         for(j=0; j < MAX_WORDS; ++j){
                printf("%s\t", strdup(buffer[i][j]));
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `char buffer[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORDS][MAX_WLENGTH];` too large for stack.

Comment: A 3D array is a bad idea. You are much better served using a dynamic array of structs where the struct would represent each line and contains a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* to point to each word in the line. (or if you had a reasonable maximum number of words per-line, you could use a simple array of pointers as the struct member). Either way you could allocate on a per-word basis that would be far more memory efficient than trying to use 3D character array (which you have found will quickly exceed the stack size of even a relatively small number of lines and words per-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking if your input file has more words than MAX_WORDS * MAX_WORDS (4096 words). So if your input file has more words then you are trying to access a location buffer[y][x][i] where y or x could be greater than 64 which might result in a segmentation fault. Use the following code instead of just y++; or x++;

```
y++;
if(y == MAX_WORDS){
 break;
}
```

Comment: yeah, absolutely. Thank you for advise, too.